# Jquery click function in a class pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I can not get the function on page .click run unless I paste in the browser console.

in my class I have:

```
var myClass = function(){
   var toggleChecked = function(){
       $('#myCheckBoxId').click(function() {  //on click                
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
            $("tr td input").each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        }else{
            $("tr td input").each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });         
        }
    });
   }

 return {
    myClass: toggleChecked
 }
}()


 $(document).ready(function(){
    myClass.toggleChecked();
 });
```

when I run the application, function not charging, but if I copy and paste in the browser console, works, someone can give me an explanation of where I am going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: `funcção` what this word meen))

Comment: I'm surprised it works even I the console, because it looks like your code has syntax errors. `return { myClass.toggleChecked }()` looks wrong on many levels.

Comment: sorry, the correct is "function"

Comment: This is a very odd pattern you're using. Is there a specific reason you're trying to organise your code in this manner?

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to improve your debugging skills. Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provide more useful context information (and help yourself).

Comment: FWIW, `return {myClass.toggleChecked}` is still wrong. You can't have a block there and `myClass` is still `undefined` and doesn't have a property `toggleChecked`. If you just want to create an object, you can do `var myClass = {toggleChecked: function() { .... }};`, but I'd choose a different variable name.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am starting my studies in javascript, jquery etc for this reason do not yet have well defined standards which are the best, this class is in a rails application, and has other methods that are working but just can not make this work.

Comment: Given your recent edit, either change the return value to `return { toggleChecked: toggleChecked };` or call the method with `myClass.myClass();`. [Learn more about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). I think you would benefit a lot from reading the whole MDN JavaScript guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try this way:

```
var myObject = {
    toggleChecked: function () {
        $('#myCheckBoxId').click(function () { //on click                
            if (this.checked) { // check select status
                $("tr td input").each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
                });
            } else {
                $("tr td input").each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    myObject.toggleChecked();
});
```

Or you can define a class if you want:

```
function MyClass () {
    this.toggleChecked = function () {
        $('#myCheckBoxId').click(function () { //on click                
            if (this.checked) { // check select status
                $("tr td input").each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
                });
            } else {
                $("tr td input").each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
                });
            }
        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = new MyClass();
    obj.toggleChecked();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4c1p502/)

Comment: Something isn't loading the function in my page, even trying what you suggest, but all the others functions its working.

Comment: Strange. Could you post somewhere more from your page's source?

Comment: Thanks Itachi, your answer helped me a lot, but the biggest problem was my technical debt, the selector was in a conflict with another, anyway i learned a lot with all answers to help me here, thanks a lot everyone